# How do I keep the selected entry in the table and use it on the next view?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Good day all I have a table that shows some basic information about actors like name, surname, age and so on and on the right of each actor I have Three buttons edit, view, delete. My problem is that when I click the view button I need to know what entry in the table was selected to be viewed so that I can show the information. The data is stored inside a JSON file and is extracted through the controller and passed into the blade.php view to show in the table.
This is the code used to show each actor in the table

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/actor/create" role="button">Actors</a>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Nationallity</th>
            <th>Options</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($jsonArray as $actor):?>
        <tr>
                
        <td>  {{$actor['actorName']}}</td>
        <td>  {{$actor['actorSurname']}}</td>
        <td>  {{$actor['actorAge']}}</td>
        <td>  {{$actor['actorNationality']}}</td>
                   
                </td>
            <td>
           
                <a href="/actor/edit" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span><strong>Edit</strong></span>            
                </a>
                <a href="/actor/show" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span><strong>View</strong></span>            
                </a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span><strong>Delete</strong></span>            
                </a>
    
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <?php endforeach;;?>                
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So when the view is selected I need to know what actor so I can show the information of that actor to the user. And how do I pass it to the next view?

My web.php File

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/', function () 
{
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get ('actor/create',[ActorsController::class, 'createView']);
Route::post ('actor/create',[ActorsController::class, 'store'])->name('actor.store');
Route::get ('actor/edit',[ActorsController::class, 'edit']);
Route::get ('actor/index',[ActorsController::class, 'index']);
Route::get ('actor/show/{actorID}',[ActorsController::class, 'show']);

Route::get ("/director/create",[DirectorController::class, 'create']);
Route::post ('director/create',[DirectorController::class, 'store'])->name('director.store');
Route::get ("/director/edit",[DirectorController::class, 'edit']);
Route::get ("/director/index",[DirectorController::class, 'index']);
Route::get ("/director/show",[DirectorController::class, 'show']);


Route::get ("/genre/create",[GenreController::class, 'create']);
Route::post ("genre/create",[GenreController::class, 'store'])->name('genre.store');
Route::get ("/genre/edit",[GenreController::class, 'edit']);
Route::get ("/genre/index",[GenreController::class, 'index'])->name('genre.index');
Route::get ("/genre/show",[GenreController::class, 'show']);


Route::get ("/movie/create",[MovieController::class, 'create']);
Route::post ('movie/create',[MovieController::class, 'store'])->name('movie.store');
Route::get ("/movie/edit",[MovieController::class, 'edit']);
Route::get ("/movie/index",[MovieController::class, 'index']);
Route::get ("/movie/show",[MovieController::class, 'show']);

Route::get ("/nationallity/create",[NationalityController::class, 'createShow']);
Route::post ("/nationallity/create",[NationalityController::class, 'store'])->name('nationallity.store');
Route::get ("/nationallity/edit",[NationalityController::class, 'edit'])->name('nationallity.edit');
Route::get ("/nationallity/index",[NationalityController::class, 'index']);
Route::get ("/nationallity/show",[NationalityController::class, 'show']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that:

1. Pass de actor **id** to the url: `<a href="/actor/show/{{ $actor['id] }}">`.
2. Define this route in `web.php` file:

`Route::get('/actor/show/{actor_id}', [ActorController::class, 'show'])`

3. In `ActorController` get the actor from DB and send this data to a view, like you did before with the actor's list table.

Comment: Thank you.So I did what you said the problem I have now is that the actor ID shows in the  url but when loading the view page it says page not found error because of the url path any suggestion?

Comment: Update your question with your `web.php` file and I'll can take a look.

Comment: I updated my Question with my web.php

Comment: Try this in the view: `<a href="{{ route('/actor/show/' . $actor['id'] }}">`

Comment: Okey so I did add this in the view but it gives an error rout not defined because it tries to put the ID in the link. LIKE:Route [/actor/show/41aae69e2ac682de64e1bf3f9e1d4955] not defined.

Comment: If you execute `php artisan route:list` in the console, what do you get? Maybe de route in the view should be `{{ route('actor/show/' . $actor['id'] }}` without slash.

Comment: GET|HEAD   actor/show/{actorID} .............................................................................................................................................................. ActorsController@show

Comment: Even when removing the slash the error stays the same

Comment: Try to add this in the route file:
`Route::get('actor/show/{actor_id}', [ActorController::class, 'show'])->name('actor.show')`

And in the view: `<a href="{{ route('actor.show', [$actor['id']] }}">`.

Comment: Thank you for the help this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

usually when you do a basic crud, endpoint will be like this:

```
baseURL/actor/IDActor (Edit PUT method)
baseURL/actor/IDActor) (Delete DELETE method)
baseURL/actor/IDActor (See data GET method)
```

In web can be done like this:

```
baseURL/actor/edit/IDActor (edit actor)
baseURL/actor/delete/IDActor) (delete actor)
baseURL/actor/IDActor (get actor info)
```

just change the method:

> `POST` for create, `PUT` for modify, `DELETE` for delete, `GET` for get
> data

more info about methods [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)
and the edit view call the Database and show the data.

If you make this your edit button was this:

```
<a href="/actor/edit/{{$actor['id']}}" class="btn btn-primary a-btn-slide-text">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span><strong>Edit</strong></span>
</a>
```

same for delete or view